# When I am trying to send parameters to HTTP post request to access a RESTful API, I am getting a "Bad Request" error

Tags: java, rest

I am coding in Java. 
API accepts input in the format: { input: "[123,345]" }

My code for HTTP Post request is as follows:
Input parameters: urlStr is the URL of the API which I want to connect to 
and paramVal is in JSONObject.toString format.

Code where I am creating paramVal value:

```
int[] param_value = {123};
JSONObject obj=new JSONObject();
obj.put("job_ids", param_value);
String response = httpPost(url,obj.toString)
```

When checked in the debugger, inside httpPost value of paramVal is 
  {"input":[123]}

```
public static String httpPost(String urlStr, String paramVal) throws Exception {
          URL url = new URL(urlStr);
          HttpURLConnection conn =
              (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
         conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
          conn.setDoOutput(true);
          conn.setDoInput(true);
          conn.setUseCaches(false);
          conn.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
          conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
              "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

          // Create the form content
         if (paramVal != null){
          OutputStream out = conn.getOutputStream();
          Writer writer = new OutputStreamWriter(out);
          writer.write(paramVal);              
          writer.close();            
          out.close();
         }

          if (conn.getResponseCode() != 200) {
            throw new IOException(conn.getResponseMessage());
          }

          // Buffer the result into a string
          BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(
              new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
          StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
          String line;
          while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line);
          }

          rd.close();

          conn.disconnect();
          return sb.toString();
        }
```

I am getting Bad Request error for this HTTP post call. 
I am pretty new to RESTful APIs and using it for the first time. Please help me find error in my code

Comment: I see two potential problems: (1) You say that it accepts `{ input: "[123,345]" }`, which is an object with one element whose value is a string. But you're sending `{"input":[123]}` which is an object with one element whose value is an *array*. (2) You are sending the wrong content type for JSON.

Comment: @RealSkeptic thank you for pointing that out. to fix the first potential issue, i did following changes in my code:                                                       int[] param_value = {123};
    JSONObject obj=new JSONObject();
   JSONArray jsArray = new JSONArray(param_value);     
    obj.put("job_ids", jsArray.toString());                               and now the value of paramValue is in {"input":"[123]"} format. But, I am still getting Bad Request error. Could you please explain how to fix content type for JSON?

Comment: Is there some code for the webservice ? Any exceptions in the log ?

Comment: Well, first, don't put a bunch of code in a comment. You can edit your answer, write "I changed so-and-so" and then in a comment say "@somebody, I edited the question, please do...". The content type should be `application/json`.

Comment: @RealSkeptic Thank you! that worked. I will keep in mind your suggestions regarding comments.